# Positivity of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix defined in the following way:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & c & 0\\c & b &-c\\0 & -c & 1-a-b\end{bmatrix}$$

I wish to show that $A=BB^t$ for some matrix $B$. Further suppose that $a,b,c\ge0$ and $abc\ne0$.

Since there is a characterization of positive elements in matrices which says that $A$ is positive iff $A$ can be written as $BB^t$ for some matrix $B$.

Towards that end, for $u=[x,y,z] \in \mathbb{R}^3$, I looked at the inner product $\langle Au,u \rangle$ and found out that $$\langle Au,u \rangle=ax^2+by^2+(1-a-b)z^2+2cxy-2cyz$$

By Hilbert's seventeenth problem, a polynomial of degree $n$ is positive iff it can be written as a sum of $2^n$ positive polynomials. How do I write this polynomial as a sum of such polynomials?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

In order for your matrix to be positive definite, all its leading principal minors must be positive.
So in addition to $a > 0$ you need $ab - c^2 > 0$ and $ab + b c^2 - a^2 b - a b^2 - c^2 > 0$.

EDIT: For your matrix to be positive semidefinite, you need
$  ab + b c^2 - a^2 b - a b^2 - c^2 \ge 0$ and $a+b-a^2-ab-b^2-2c^2\ge 0$.

Comment: A quibble: If $A=BB^t$ but $B$ is 2-by-3 (or equivalently, if $B$ is 3-by-3 but one of its columns is zero) then $A$ will have a zero eigenvalue and thus be positive semi-definite rather than positive. (Whether $A$ should be PD or PSD is a bit ambiguous from the question.) In that case the relevant criterion is that all its principal minors be non-negative, not just the leading principal minors.